# TYPO3 outputs HTML5 tags as entities

Tags: html, tags, typo3, typoscript

I am having a rather weird issue with my TYPO3 6.1 installation.

It is outputting HTML5 tags as entites, so if I inserts an imageelement it will output the HTML like this

```
    <p>
     <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-center csc-textpic-above">
       <div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap">
          <div class="csc-textpic-center-outer">
             <div class="csc-textpic-center-inner">
                &lt;figure class=&quot;csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-last&quot;&gt;<img src="fileadmin/billeder/forandring.jpg" width="960" height="540"  alt="">&lt;/figure&gt;
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </p>
```

Which gives me this in the FE:

```
<figure class="csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-last"></figure>
```

The image is displayed correctly in the figure tag as it is a normal img tag.

A HTML5 video will output the video tags as entites

```
<p> &lt;video id=&quot;video_3&quot; class=&quot;video-js vjs-default-skin&quot; width=&quot;960&quot; height=&quot;540&quot; preload=&quot;auto&quot; controls data-setup='{&quot;techOrder&quot;:[&quot;youtube&quot;,&quot;html5&quot;,&quot;flash&quot;]}'&gt;</p>
```

I am using some TS to remove unwanted HTML, but I don't think that is what causes it

```
tt_content {
   stdWrap.prefixComment >
   stdWrap.dataWrap >
   stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject >
   stdWrap.innerWrap2 >
}

lib {
   parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.addAttributes.P.class >
   parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks = h2,h3,h4
   parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks.h2.stripNL = 1
   stdheader {
     1.headerClass >
     2.headerClass >
     3.headerClass >
     stdWrap {
       dataWrap >
       prefixComment >
       }
     10.stdWrap.wrap >
   }
}
```

and my pageconfig is this:

```
##################################
# CONFIGURATION                  #
##################################
config {
   doctype = html5
   xmlprologue = none
   disablePrefixComment = 1
   disableImgBorderAttr = 1
   inlineStyle2TempFile = 1
   pageTitleFirst = 1
   removeDefaultJS = 1
   removeDefaultCss = 1
   simulateStaticDocuments = 0
   baseUrl = http://www.domain.com/
   tx_realurl_enable = 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed!

Changed

`<f:format.html>{content_image}</f:format.html>`

to

```
<f:format.raw>{content_image}</f:format.raw>
```